# window.maximize() fails when window is minimized electron

Tags: electron, trayicon, tray

I have created an electron app with a tray Icon.
When I right click the tray icon I show a menu with 4 options:

- Minimize
- Maximize
- Restart
- Exit

Here is the code that creates the tray Icon:

```
    trayIcon = new Tray('icons/foo.png');
    const trayMenuTemplate = [{
        label: 'Maximize',
        click:(_,window)=>{
            window.maximize();
        }
    }, {
        label: 'Minimize',
        click:(_,window)=>{
            window.minimize();
        }
    }, {
        label: 'Restart'
    }, {
        type: 'separator'
    }, {
        label: 'Quit',
        role: 'quit'
    }];
```

However I have a problem.When I click Minimize and then I click Maximize I get an error saying `Cannnot read property maximize of null`
Any ideas?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always check if it's minimized and restore it as a workaround. I don't think this is such a big deal.

To check and restore it you can use this:

```
if (window.isMinimized()) {
    window.restore();
}
```

The whole thing would be like this:

```
{
    label: 'Maximize',
    click:(_,window)=>{
        if (window.isMinimized()) {
            window.restore();
        }
        window.maximize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tray is not bound to any BrowserWindow, thus `window` is null. You can just use your `mainWindow` reference if you created the tray menu in your Main-process or `remote.getCurrentWindow()` if you are in the Renderer.